# Meteor and Blade with "foreach"

Tags: meteor, laravel-blade

Using Meteor with Handlebars I can list out items from a collection like this

```
Template.content.clients = ->
  Clients.find({})
```

And in the template

```
<#each clients>
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
</each>
```

For Blade I have tried

```
if Meteor.isClient

  Template.content.clients = ->
    Clients.find({})

  $ ->
    $("body").html Meteor.render Template.something
```

And in the template

```
foreach clients as client
  h2= client.name
```

The Blade version doesn't work, and gives the error "has no method observe".

Can someone please give a working example of listing a collection in Meteor with Blade?

Comment: This might be a bug in Blade. I have added [issue #102](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues/102).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Blade and appears to have been resolved.

See [issue #102](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues/102)